# How can I find the true key value in the object and convert to an Object to an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an object like this:

```
{ status: true, count: true, period: false, price: false }


[ 'status', 'count' ]
```

How can I find the true key value in the object and convert to an Object to an array?

Comment: [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: `Object.entries(array).filter(([,$])=>$).map(([$])=>$)`

Comment: `Object.entries(theObject).filter(([ _key, value ]) => value === true).map(([ key ]) => key)`. Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - you can drop the `_key` :p

Comment: @Bravo That’s a matter of preference.

Comment: my linter is pretty picky about *unused variables* (though, I know it lets this through :p )

Comment: const obj = { status: true, count: true, period: false, price: false }

const result = Object.keys(obj).filter((key) => {
 if (obj[key] === true) {
  return key;
 }
});

console.log(result);